# Select file from Downloads to upload via web form

Tags: file-system

I'm on a Samsung Galaxy S3 and want to upload a file from my Downloads folder to a website using a form on that web page.

But when I click the button to browse for a file to upload, I can only select files from my Music and Gallery folders, or the camera.

I tried putting the files in my Gallery or Music, but those apps only display music or image files.

So how can I browse to my Downloads folder and select a file from there to upload?

I can't quite believe I'm having such an idiotic problem.

Comment: What version of Android are you on?

Comment: You might wish to try installing a [file manager](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman). Those often "chime in" when an "select a file" action is invoked by the user, so you then could chose the file-manager when asked for an app to "perform this action with" – and then of course give you the freedom to select any file, not only "gallery items".